# How Do I Stop Visual Studio from Generating Setter Calls in my UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-generation

I have created a couple of controls that inherit from UserControl for my Winform application. They both have parameterless constructors, as is required.  When I drop them onto my main form, I get an error in Visual Studio at design-time where it cannot render the form.

What I discovered is that, in the form's Designer.cs file, where my control is instantiated, the IDE is placing a line there that calls one of my setters.  `BlockKey = 0`.  Well, the code behind the setter is calling some other code, and quickly a NullReferenceException gets thrown because the form's not running; that other code is not prepared to produce anything at that point.

If I manually remove the setter line, the error goes away.  But closing and re-opening, or re-compiling, the IDE puts the line back in again.  I tried decorating, inside the UserControl, the setter with `[DefaultValue(false)]`, thinking this would suppress the design-time call to the setter, but it did not.

How can I get rid of that line in the Designer?  Or am I expected to do write some preventative code inside the setter instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute` attribute on your property with it set to `Hidden`.

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public int BlockKey
{
    get { return 0; }
    set { /* Do something */ }
}
```

Alternatively if you need more specific logic (i.e. only serialize in certain conditions) then you must create a function that returns a bool and has a specific name in the format of `bool ShouldSerialize*PropertyName*()`

```
bool ShouldSerializeBlockKey()
{
     return false;
}
```

(NOTE: I forget whether this function must be public or not...)

Comment: Oh by the way, the `DefaultValue` attribute is what the designer's property window will use to enable the right-click Reset functionality.

Comment: Here's the doco on the more manual ShouldSerialize method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Is there something similar for methods?  In my constructor I have a call to another method that goes to the database for some data to populate a combo box.  That call is again crashing the form at design-time.  What is the best practice on this?

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll have to use the protected `DesignMode` property to segregate the non-designer code.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute`.  This controls whether or not the designer will serialize out *default* values for a particular attribute or not

- [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx)

If you specify the properties as `Hidden` the designer won't add values for them